# Lenovo Bios Reset on Boot

Tags: boot, kernel, lenovo, bios, reset

I recently switched from arch-linux (antergos) to ubuntu, because I had some Issues I could not get hold on.
One Issue was that on everyboot the BIOS notified "Configuration changed. Restarting the system", after which it restarts with resetted settings.
On Antergos I could fix this by adding this kernel parameter: `acpi_enforce_resources=lax`

Now on Ubuntu 17.10 I have exactly the same problem but the kernel parameter does not do its job.

Im operating a Lenovo Thinkpad Yoga S1 and already changed the CMOS Battery.
As configuring the kernel on the other OS I do not think that it's a hardware related issue.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I can confirm that I have the same issue with an identical setup: 17.10 and a Lenovo Thinkpad Yoga S1.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot save the BIOS settings in Lenovo laptop, most probably you are impacted with the [recent bug in Ubuntu 17.10](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1734147).

Basically, several Lenovo and some Ace devices have troubles changing the BIOS settings. The issue is critical and [Canonical has temporarily removed Ubuntu 17.10 ISO downloads](https://itsfoss.com/ubuntu-17-10-bios-bug/).

Answer (score 0):

The only way to solve the ubuntu bios bug is to replace the Bios chip on the motherboard as seen in this video https://youtu.be/iiFHhEqluCY

Comment: fixes have been found & documented (and not requiring hardware changes)  -- refer https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1734147